# Xamarin - Scrollview content is overlapping the static layout

Tags: xaml, xamarin

how can I send the scroll view content to the back of the image? It is overlapping the image when scrolling. Basically, I want the content inside scrollview to get "send to back" of the image when the user scrolls up. Below is the xaml that I am using.

```
<StackLayout>
<Grid>
    <controls:CustomFrame CornerRadius="0,0,20,20"
                              BackgroundColor="#E45F0F"
                              HeightRequest="170"
                              Padding="0">
        <Image Source="ShirtRack2.jpg"
                   Aspect="AspectFill"></Image>
    </controls:CustomFrame>
    <Frame CornerRadius="50"
               HasShadow="False"
               BackgroundColor="White"
               HeightRequest="100"
               WidthRequest="100"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               Margin="0,0,0,-45"
               VerticalOptions="End"
               Padding="5">
        <Frame CornerRadius="50"
                   Padding="0"
                   IsClippedToBounds="True"
                   HasShadow="False">
            <Image Source="ShirtRack.jpg"
                       Aspect="AspectFill"></Image>
        </Frame>
    </Frame>
</Grid>
<ScrollView VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never">
    <StackLayout Padding="25,0,25,0">
        <Label Text="Store Name"
                   FontSize="24"
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                   FontFamily="PSemiBold"
                   Margin="0,50,0,5"
                   TextColor="#262626" />
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
</StackLayout>
```

[image: Output]

Comment: You'll probably need to use a Grid instead of stack layout to obtain that. An Absolute layout would also work. Basically, you need a layout that allows overlapping. StackLayout does not.

Comment: @Andrew I am thinking nested Grid, but can't seem to figure out how to structure it.

Answer (score 1):

I got it now. All I had to do was change the StackLayout to Grid then changed the orders. All "VerticalOptions" was the missing piece that I have been looking for.

Comment: Please upload the new XAML to make it clear how you solved the problem.